# xlink:href attribute on <use> tag throws typescript error when used in tsx file

Tags: typescript, error-handling, href, xlink, tsx

I have simple code that includes svg icon with `<use>` tag into web-component created with stencjiljs (tsx syntax). However, when I add `xlink:href` attribute to `<use>` tag I get error `Identifier expected`.

```
Example code: 
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
   tag: 'example-component',
   styleUrl: 'example-component.scss',
})

 export class ExampleComponent {
     render() {
        return (
            <svg>
                <use href="#iconid" xlink:href="#iconid"/>
            </svg>
       );
    }
}
```

I tired to search for tsx/jsx specific solution but all I got is that it's `xLinkHref` in React, which doesn't work in this case.

I there specific way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one works fine for me. My component extension is `.tsx`

```
<use href="#iconid" xlinkHref="#iconid"/></use>
```

May be because you have missed the closing tag.

Comment: The tag is self-closed. But I noticed that I was using `xLinkHref` instead of `xlinkHref`. The later actually renders but to `href` not to `xlink:href`. But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Worked for me.  This seems like it should be the accepted answer @niemaszoka

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Typescript will not support namespaced attributes: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7411

I would propose to just skip JSX and use raw JSX component factory.
In React one would use `React.createElement` like this:

```
<use>
    {React.createElement('use', {href:"#iconid", "xlink:href": "#iconid"})}
</use>
```

In don't know how the `stenciljs` factory is named, but if it's compatible with JSX its `createElement` must have API very similar to one shown above.

(edit: s/createComponent/createElement/g)